# Custom H:M:S field type in excel, when loaded in R left with a 3 to 4 whole digit number. How to load it back to its original display?

Tags: r, excel, time

I have a column for time. The original result was 12:30:04 AM.

When I loaded the file in R though the read_excel function , it became 1804.

I want the result to re appear as 12:30:04 AM or 00:30:04 whichever is feasible.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to be

```
df$Time<-format(.POSIXct(df$time, "UTC"), "%H:%M:%S")
```